# Create typescript object dynamically?

Tags: typescript

I want to have a typescript object for color variations like this:

```
type Colors = {
  blue: string;
  blue[10]: string;
  blue[20]: string;
  blue[30]: string;
  blue[40]: string;
  green: string;
  green[20]: string;
  green[40]: string;
  green[60]: string;
  green[80]: string;
}
```

I want to be able to get a color by using just its name or a variation of the color by adding a bracket like I'm accessing an object property. Note each color has different variations. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
type Variations = '' | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40;
type Variations2 = '' | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;
type TAllColors = {
  [P in Variations as `blue${P}`]: string;
}&
{
  [P in Variations2 as `green${P}`]: string;
}
```

However, this creates a type thats like this:

```
type Colors = {
    "blue": string;
    "blue10": string;
    "blue20": string;
    "blue30": string;
    "blue40": string;
} & {
    "green": string;
    "green20": string;
    "green40": string;
    "green60": string;
    "green80": string;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can make it so the color variations are actually an object that I can access like `blue[20]` and `green[80]`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big problem will be that you're trying to use `blue` both as the name of a string property and as the name of an object property (with properties like `10`, `20`, etc.) at the same time, [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJwM5QLxQN4CgoFQBGCArhAFxSrDICWAdgOZQBkO+hXAjAAxU16zANycuBAEz9qtRk1HjCAZmmC5CxVAAsq2SLFQAvhoJNkECAwF6W7PJqhTrQ+Qa47n6t4QBsulybiABz+XlyGuMa4QA):

```typescript
// WON'T WORK
type Colors = {
    blue: string & {
        10: string;
        20: string;
        30: string;
        40: string;
    };
    green: string & {
        20: string;
        40: string;
        60: string;
        80: string;
    }
};
```

But `string` is a string primitive, it can't have those properties. It could be an augmented `String` *object*, [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZ2Eg9gOwM5QLxQBEAbgIwAMhUAPkcQEyU10DMTtJALJQNwBQoSLEQo0WbPXx1GVDsW6y6ANnZ0AHLwHhoAFQCCAGwMBhdAfQJcBAN58o9qACMDAVwgAuKAGVgyTAHMoADIoWwdwqABtAAUoJExhZFQMHABdT2xfeP9+cIBfXId-BAgITE8fP0CQsIj7GLiE+CSxHHp0qEyqwvsCvj6+AGNxYChh80tPfSNTCatQuwdnN08AeUcAKwhB4AA6OGxsJH9MAApMCAB3byyA08JliEIASgAaBbr7MnJPB9cICiEV6LOoMH5ER4yYGfKDENi-R5sIEgiLycF-NwKaGfYgAVnRj3xQKgAHoSVAAOrQS5wTCjWlQCAIBAWKAACyZEBReTeKOKpXKUHWWx2+0OxzOF2ulWy935ZRe71qoMYv3lmChKPCaLVJTKWK1DmIKl1ApUyJhxA0prKGgtDh5wL6QA), but note that we can't reliably use `10`, `15`, etc. because if the string itself is long enough, that will conflict with the usual string indexes, so we need some kind of prefix:

```typescript
type Colors = {
    blue: String & {
        v10: string;
        v20: string;
        v30: string;
        v40: string;
    };
    green: String & {
        v20: string;
        v40: string;
        v60: string;
        v80: string;
    }
};
const colors: Colors = {
    blue: Object.assign(new String("blue"), {
        v10: "blue10",
        v20: "blue20",
        v30: "blue30",
        v40: "blue40",
    }),
    green: Object.assign(new String("green"), {
        v20: "green20",
        v40: "green40",
        v60: "green60",
        v80: "green80",
    }),
};
```

...but you'll have to remember to convert `colors.blue` and `colors.green` to primitive strings when you want primitive strings. But you *can* do that; the basic version might be [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZ2Eg9gOwM5QLxQDkAbgIwAMhUAPkcQEyU10DMTtJALJQNwBQoSLEQo0WbPXx1GVDsW6y6ANnZ0AHLwHhoAFQCCAGwMBhdAfQJcBAN58o9qACMDAVwgAuKAGVgyTAHMoADIoWwdwqABtAAUoJExhZFQMHABdT2xfeP9+cIBfXId-BAgITE8fP0CQsIj7GLiE+CSxHHp0qEyqwvsCvj6+AGNxYChh80tPfSNTCatQuwdnN08AeUcAKwhB4AA6OGxsJH9MAApMCAB3byyA04AiZYh7gEoAGgW6+zJyT0fXCAUe5vRZ1Bi-KD-NyMYGgiLENh-J5sWFfKDyCFQiDcVFfYgAVkxT0JwKgAHoyVAAOrQS5wTCjelQCAIBAWKAACxZEDheXecOKpXKUHWWx2+0OxzOF2ulWyD0FZVeH1qYMYf0VmBhILRGI1JTKOJ1eJU+qFKlxYI0ZrKGktUD5IL6QA):

```typescript
type Variations = "v10" | "v20" | "v30" | "v40";
type Variations2 = "v20" | "v40" | "v60" | "v80";
type TAllColors = {
    blue: String & {
        [P in Variations]: string;
    };
    green: String & {
        [P in Variations2]: string;
    };
};

const colors: TAllColors = {
    blue: Object.assign(new String("blue"), {
        v10: "blue10",
        v20: "blue20",
        v30: "blue30",
        v40: "blue40",
        v50: "blue50", // We want an error here
    }),
    green: Object.assign(new String("green"), {
        v20: "green20",
        v40: "green40",
        v60: "green60",
        v80: "green80",
    }),
};
```

But there's a developer experience issue there, as you can see — we don't get an error for an invalid variant definition. We can fix that by using a specific function to create the objects, [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZ2Eg9gOwM5QLxQBEAbgIwAMhUAPkcQEyU10DMTtJALJQNwBQoSLEQo0WbPXx1GVDsW6y6ANnZ0AHLwHhoAFQCCAGwMBhdAfQJcBAN58o9qACMDAVwgAuKAGVgyTAHMoADJhZFQMHAB5RwArCABjYH4HKH8ECAhMTx8-QJD4MLEcemi4xP4AX34tIQLRCOxShOApWxSAbQAFKCRMUPrxAF1PbF9e-0r+QWg68PES2ObWuwcunr7ZoolhqFHcyb4AMxdMRIioAFs4AGsIAqbEgB4CgD4ACive+FcPXbGAgA0UGIIjmOE8BQAlFA2g50sAXAg+g9gAA6ODYbBIfyYN6YCAAd28-38HzgXzgP0hQJBhQakMqfD48XELRZ5ksnn0RlMHKsMJW9mcbk8V1u90WT02DRR70IwoghCBsJS9jI5E88p+FCVgtVDA1RAVMgBepSxDYmoVbF1qoc8kNWrcClNdrVAFZHQrPUqoAB6P1QADiEGAuGAAAtoBAEAgLFAMVAACYQLHpJN6irUvVpDJZS43O6IFHPUFbBZlYBy3OZX0q-WMTU1zAms327hN9KZF1ttUqTt5lS2t3EDQDzIaYf2LOmqp8IA):

```typescript
type Variations = "v10" | "v20" | "v30" | "v40";
type Variations2 = "v20" | "v40" | "v60" | "v80";
type TAllColors = {
    blue: String & VariationsObject;
    green: String & Variations2Object;
};

type VariationsObject = {
    [P in Variations]: string;
};
type Variations2Object = {
    [P in Variations2]: string;
};
function makeVarObject<Var>(mainValue: string, variations: Var) {
    return Object.assign(new String(mainValue), variations);
}

const colors: TAllColors = {
    blue: makeVarObject<VariationsObject>("blue", {
        v10: "blue10",
        v20: "blue20",
        v30: "blue30",
        v40: "blue40",
        v50: "blue50", // Gets the error as desired
    }),
    green: makeVarObject<Variations2Object>("green", {
        v20: "green20",
        v40: "green40",
        v60: "green60",
        v80: "green80",
    }),
};
```

**But**, I'd strongly recommend using a `default` property or something rather than trying to make `blue` and `green` both strings and objects so your type would look like this (it also lets us get rid of the prefix on the numbers):

```typescript
type Colors = {
    blue: {
        default: string;
        10: string;
        20: string;
        30: string;
        40: string;
    };
    green: {
        default: string;
        20: string;
        40: string;
        60: string;
        80: string;
    }
};
```

We can do that with a quite minor change to your original code, [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZ2Eg9gOwM5QLxQBEAJhAGZwCuANsIVAD5QCMADI1AEztMDMPUACysA3AChQkWIhRos2TviKkKNOh24dhHAGwCAHKInhoAFQCC1agGF01dAlwEA3mKjuoAI2qUIALihXD2CoAG0ABSgkTGlkVAwcAF0A7GBkTABzcWCAXwAaNw8MhAgITACgkPcIqJj4OLkcTmSoVPSswvd8sRzxMQBjeWAoQftHAIsrWzGnQM6vH385qvcVKloAwm9fQgKVllZN7Yg2Xfng7iPF7jP9-ivffluV4QeIYWeqgFZDomOf3ZQAD0QKgAFEEAgHFA4LhSNgkCViPNusFiqVyssVms1Jt0WVPiFLkR8ZgbnsXr9CKSPhSqno8SUynpCcFDIyMYZCd1ekA):

```typescript
type Variations = "default" | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40;
type Variations2 = "default" | 20 | 40 | 60 | 80;
type TAllColors = {
    blue: {
        [P in Variations]: string;
    },
    green: {
        [P in Variations2]: string;
    },
};

const colors: TAllColors = {
    blue: {
        default: "blue",
        10: "blue10",
        20: "blue20",
        30: "blue30",
        40: "blue40",
        50: "blue50", // Error as desired
    },
    green: {
        default: "green",
        20: "green20",
        40: "green40",
        60: "green60",
        80: "green80",
    },
};
```

Comment: Ah, so basically there's no way of just having `"blue"` and also having `blue[10]`, `blue[20]`, etc. Not sure if I want the developer to have to type in `blue.default` so I guess I'll just go with what I have now and make it `blue10`, `blue20`, etc... Oh well...

Comment: @MarksCode - Well, there is a way, but it means `blue` is a String object (the middle of the answer), not a primitive string. In a lot of cases that won't matter, but sometimes it will, and it might trip you up in subtle ways. For instance, `colors.blue === "blue"` would be false even though `colors.blue == "blue"` is true (assuming for that example that the value of `blue` is `"blue"`).

Comment: That example is not working for me. I'm getting an error: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '5' of object '[object String]'`

Comment: @MarksCode - Which example? Can you give me a playground link? (Note: If the URL is long, you can use https://tsplay.dev/ to shorten it.)

Comment: @MarksCode - It took me **ages** to figure out why you're getting that error and I'm not: You're using `5`, and the string itself has more than five letters, and of course `string[5]` is the 6th letter of the string, which is read-only. It *just happened* that my code used names shorter than 10, so there was no conflict. You'll need something to differentiate the numbers from string indexes, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Nn45kW). I should have seen that coming.

Comment: Got it. Well I'm not sure if I like how logging out `colors.niceNavy` gives: `String: "#012754"`. So I think I'll just go with your `default` method.

Comment: I guess the only way to really do something like what I'm trying to accomplish is to make each color a function that takes the variation as a parameter, and returns the corresponding color. The default if no parameter would be the base color.

Comment: @MarksCode - How do you *use* the colors? Will they only be used in ways that will implicitly convert them to primitive strings? (We can actually fix the `[object String]` logging problem using [`Symbol.toStringTag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag) [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Wkjzpm).)

Comment: They're used in a Material-UI theme. so I do like: `background-color: theme.palette.indigo`. I was trying to make it so I can do like `bacgkround-color: theme.palette.indigo[50]` but I guess that's not really possible.

Comment: @MarksCode - Yeah, I think you're best off with `background-color: theme.palette.indigo.default` and `background-color: theme.palette.indigo[50]` (the last approach above). We *could* add a `toString` method to the objects so that if you used `theme.palette.indigo` and it was implicitly converted to string, you'd get the default.

Comment: Will do. Thanks TJ, I hope to one day be a Typescript wizard like you!

Comment: @MarksCode - LOL! I'm very much a beginner-to-medium level TypeScript person. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do, even if you could type it in TypeScript (which you can't for good reasons that follow), is not implementable. The reason is that a variable or property cannot be both a primitive type and an object at the same time.

So, in your initial `Colors` example type you specify `blue` to be both a string (primitive value) and an object or array with certain indices. JavaScript is a very liberal language but it will not accept that.

Take for example:

```
const blue = 'abc';
blue[10] = 'def';
```

If you log `blue` you will get `abc`, but if you log `blue[10]` you will get undefined. It will look for the character at index 10 of a string.

Therefore I suggest to look for a variation of the problem, e.g. either using only strings or only objects/arrays. An alternative solution would be to use helper functions to supply the colors.